# Monitoring options for a medium sized company

Tags: data-visualization, monitoring, logs

I've been set on the task of investigating different monitoring options for the new software department at a consultancy firm. The company is new to proper monitoring and has very little in place.

We need log management, error monitoring, alerting, database and API and VM metric monitoring as well as visualisation options.

So far I've investigated options like datadog and sumologic, which would be ideal but are very pricey. I was wondering if anyone had any experience or recommendations for free options.

So far I'm mainly looking at Zabbix, but it seems like (although it does a lot) it has a very steep learning curve that each developer would be forced to go through.

Any experiences or opinions on the pros and cons of free/open-source options would be much appreciated.

Comment: Someone has to say `nagios` so I will

Comment: When Nagios is mentioned by someone, someone else has to mention [Checkmk](https://checkmk.com/) I guess?

Comment: Does Nagios Core offer sufficient functionality? It seems, from all I can find online, that Core (as in the free part of Nagios) is insufficient. The Nagios site itself says that: "Performing checks, sending notifications, processing performance data, and many other tasks are generally out-of-scope for Nagios Core and are handled by other Nagios projects." [link](https://www.nagios.org/projects/nagios-core)

Comment: "other Nagios projects" just means nagios plugins, which are free and abundant.

Comment: @Tandrews, moreover these plugins are in most of the cases few lines scripts. If you want product which will cover most of your requirements be ready to pay. And even then you should customize some of the probes and add own probes.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios is very good software, very flexible, very powerful. I managed 6 servers with >40k probes, >2k servers and I edit/create >100 plugins to monitor different services, parameters, etc.

Yes, it is not point-and-click, it take some time to start thinking Nagios, but after this it become very sample and fast.